# Finding the center of mass when mass is equal to 0

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to designate the center of mass of a curve:

$K = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x(t) = 2\cos(t), y(t) = 2\sin(t), z(t) = t, t \in [-2\pi, 2\pi]\}. $

The density of $K$ is $\rho(x,y,z) = x + y + z$.

The problem is that the mass of $K$ is equal to $ \int\limits_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} \rho(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \sqrt{(\dot{x(t)})^{2} + (\dot{y(t)})^{2} + (\dot{z(t)})^{2}} dt = 0 $. How to compute center of mass then?

Comment: It seems that you have negative mass density. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was wondering about it. It woudn't be a problem if $t \in [0,2\pi]$, but does the density make sense for $t \in [-2\pi,0]$? The mass would be negative then.

Comment: You can define the center of mass as the point $P$ for which the integral $\int (p-P)\rho(p)d^3p =0$ , so you don't have to worry about dividing by zero total mass

Comment: Would you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Please do not use inappropriate tags. I have removed the differential geometry tag.